# Installing Pillow FreeType Support in Django VirtualEnv

Tags: django, django-templates, pip

I am trying to enable Freetype support in one of my Django projects.  Pillow installs perfectly fine, but I am unclear as to how I am supposed to enable FreeType support inside a VirtualEnv.  The Pillow docs say that build option is to `--enable-freetype` but I am sure that this is for installing systemwide and not with PIP. I have only ever used PIP and haven't actually 'built' packages from scratch and maybe thats the issue, but the docs and Google searches are a bit all over the place. I develop locally on a MAC and my projects are hosted at [www.pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) - Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing the FreeType libraries at the system level. For example on Ubuntu / Debian:

```
apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

However IIRC, you do not have access to apt-get on PythonAnywhere. I suggest that you contact their support and see if that library can be included for your account. If they can do that, just reinstall Pillow to get support for FreeType.

Answer (score 2):

Pillow on PythonAnywhere already has freetype enabled. You don't need to do anything except pip install it.

Comment: Sweet!!  Thank you.